# Did a VS code update change the syntax highlighting of JavaScript classes?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Previously, if I had a JavaScript class instantiated with

```
let myInstance = new MyClass();
```

"MyClass" would be of textmate scope "entity.name.type.js" (making it a nice yellow color in the Night Owl theme).

Now, after a recent update, "MyClass" is blue just like a normal function call. When I inspect "MyClass" using "Inspect editor tokens and scopes", I see that the textmate scopes does not include entity.name.type.js, and instead uses "entity.name.function.js".

Is this intended? How can I get the old textmate scopes classification back?

I had really liked having different colors for class instantiations and normal function calls, but this update has made the two use the same textmate scope value. Is this a VS Code update, or is it something specific to the Night Owl theme?

Comment: Could be the separate colors came from semantic highlighting (which happens on top of syntax highlighting) and that is switched off for you currently. Check the associated setting to ensure semantic highlighting is enabled.

Comment: You're right, it seems like this was changed :( - It's not the first change they do making it more difficult or impossible to fine tune.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but I solved with double selector:

```
"textMateRules": [{
            "scope": "new.expr.js entity.name.function.js",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#4EC9B0",
            }
        }]
```